# Segmentation fault with large incomprehensible error?

Tags: c, string, file, sorting, segmentation-fault

This program is meant to sort words alphabetically, either words that are imputed into it, or from a text file. It compiles just fine, but when I run it, I get a large mass of text. Here is a small sample of it:
`:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
v=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:`
It kinda looks like some file formats or something?
This is followed by the words:
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
I'm compiling in GCC on Ubuntu.
The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MO 109 // 109 is ASCII for "m".
#define FO 102 // 102 is ASCII for "f".
#define OO 101 // 101 is ASCII for "e" and denotes an error.

int main() // Main part of program.
{
        int i, j; // Counter integer assignment.
        int n = 100; // assignment of integer for the number of strings.
        char a; // For the m/f (manual or file) option.
        char str[100][100]; // Str is the main string to be sorted.
        char temp[100]; // Temp is to switch the values for bubble sorting.
        for(i = 0; i < 1; a = OO)
        {
                printf("To input text manually, press m. To sort a file, press f. \n");   
                // M/f option.
                scanf("%c", &a); // Gets m/f option.
                if(a == MO || a == FO) // Checks for valid input.
                {
                        i = 2; // Escape from loop with valid input.
                }
                if(a != MO && a != FO) // Invalid input.
                {
                        printf("Please insert a valid response. ");
                        i = 0; // Continue loop until a valid input is reached.
                }
        } 
        if(a == MO) // Manual insert option.
        {
                puts("Enter the number of strings to be sorted.");
                scanf("%d", &n); // Gets number of strings.
                for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                {
                        gets(str[i]); // Gets strings from user.
                }
        }
        if(a == FO) // File option.
        {
                char b[100]; // File address of text file to be sorted.
                FILE * f; // Text file.
                printf("Enter file path of file to be sorted.");
                scanf("%c", b); // Gets file path.
                f = fopen(b, "r"); // Opens file.
                fgets(*str, 100, f); // Coverts file into string str.
                fclose(f); // Closes file.
        }
        for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) // Begin bubble sort.
        {
                for(j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
                {
                        if(strcmp(str[i], str[j]) > 0) // Checks alphabetical value.
                        {
                                 strcpy(temp, str[i]); // Switch two strings.
                                 strcpy(str[i], str[j]);
                                 strcpy(str[j], temp);
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("The sorted string:");
        for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
                puts(str[i]); // Prints final output.
        }
        return 0; // End of main.
}
```

A Google search told me that a segmentation fault usually means that I'm referring to a place in the memory that doesn't exist. But I couldn't find any advice on how to fix it, or even what the problem is specifically.
If someone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: There are many things wrong with that code.

Comment: Could you tell me what's wrong with it? I'm not very good at this sort of thing.

Comment: @user2973526 For starters, use `'m'`, `'f'`, and `'e'` instead of those #defines.

Comment: Hint1: if you define an array to be a[100], then it's elements are a[0],...a[99]

Comment: Don't ever use gets for any reason. Use fgets instead.

Comment: Also, using `for(i = 0; i < 1; a = OO)` and setting `i` within the loop is bad style, and almost certainly not doing what you want. Better to use a do-while and use that validity check to your advantage.

Comment: Then there's encapsulation....

Comment: @user2973526 The for loop that I pointed out earlier almost certainly doesn't do what you want. If I'm reading it right, `a` will always contain the ascii value for `'e'` when you exit the loop.

Comment: Oh yes! I see what I did wrong. I'll adjust my loop. Thank you. Also I  changed my gets function gets to scanf, because I don't really know how to use fgets. Thanks for all the advice!

Comment: If you're going to use `for` as an infinite loop, don't use variables.  Just use `for(;;)` and then `break` when you want to exit the loop.  If you want a loop that just breaks when a value is set, use `while`.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments to your question says, there are many things wrong with the code...

For example

```
for(i = 0; i < 1; a = OO)
{
  // ...
}
```

At the end of that loop, `a == OO` always, because you tell it to equal OO in the last part of the `for` statement. So all your work to set the value of `a` inside the 'loop' is wasted.

But getting back to the point of the question, about the seg-fault: You're right that it's caused by referring to memory that your program doesn't own. In your case, it's probably because of this:

```
   int n = 100; // assignment of integer for the number of strings.
   // ...
   char str[100][100]; // Str is the main string to be sorted.
   // ...

   for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) // Begin bubble sort.
    {
            for(j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                    if(strcmp(str[i], str[j]) > 0) // Checks alphabetical value.
```

str[100] is beyond the limits of your array. An array with 100 elements will use indicies from 0 to 99. str[100] would access the '101st' element, which is out of bounds and thus can cause a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small modification to your algorithm and it works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MO 109 // 109 is ASCII for "m".
#define FO 102 // 102 is ASCII for "f".
#define OO 101 // 101 is ASCII for "e" and denotes an error.

int main() // Main part of program.
{
    int i, j; // Counter integer assignment.
    int n = 100; // assignment of integer for the number of strings.
    char a; // For the m/f (manual or file) option.
    char str[100][100]; // Str is the main string to be sorted.
    char temp[100]; // Temp is to switch the values for bubble sorting.
    a = OO;
    i=0;
    while(i < 1)
    {
        printf("To input text manually, press m. To sort a file, press f. \n");
        // M/f option.
        scanf("%c", &a); // Gets m/f option.
        if(a == MO || a == FO) // Checks for valid input.
        {
            i = 2; // Escape from loop with valid input.
        }
        if(a != MO && a != FO) // Invalid input.
        {
            printf("Please insert a valid response. ");
            i = 0; // Continue loop until a valid input is reached.
        }
    }
    if(a == MO) // Manual insert option.
    {
        puts("Enter the number of strings to be sorted.");
        scanf("%d", &n); // Gets number of strings.
        for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            gets(str[i]); // Gets strings from user.
        }
    }
    if(a == FO) // File option.
    {
        char b[100]; // File address of text file to be sorted.
        FILE * f; // Text file.
        printf("Enter file path of file to be sorted.");
        scanf("%c", b); // Gets file path.
        f = fopen(b, "r"); // Opens file.
        fgets(*str, 100, f); // Coverts file into string str.
        fclose(f); // Closes file.
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) // Begin bubble sort.
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(str[i], str[j]) > 0) // Checks alphabetical value.
            {
                strcpy(temp, str[i]); // Switch two strings.
                strcpy(str[i], str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The sorted string:");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        puts(str[i]); // Prints final output.
    }
    return 0; // End of main.
}
```